# HOW TO ADD COLUMN TO 'Order Total Report' GRID and display custom customer data to new column in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-grid

There are so many post discussing how to add column to sales order grid, but no one discussed about HOW TO ADD COLUMN TO `Order Total Report` GRID (`REPORTS > Customers > Order Total`) and display custom customer data to new column in magento2? Can someone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try following way to add customer email to that grid:

> app/code/SR/MagentoStackExchange/view/adminhtml/layout/reports_report_customer_totals_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.report.grid.columnSet">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.report.grid.columnSet.customer_email" as="email">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</argument>
                    <argument name="sortable" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
                    <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">customer_email</argument>
                    <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">customer_email</argument>
                    <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                    <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-name</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: how to display custom customer attribute value to newly added column? It's showing new column 'Affiliate ID' but not displaying value of custom attribute.

Comment: What do you mean by customer attribute? Check sales_order table column.