# Magento2 - Ordered Products Report sorting columns

Tags: magento2, grid, admin-panel, reports, grid-layout

`Magento Admin > Reports > Products > Ordered`
I have created new columns(SKU) using the help of these two links in the report grid.

[Magento 2 ordered product report](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263037/magento-2-ordered-product-report)

[HOW TO ADD COLUMN TO 'Order Total Report' GRID and display custom customer data to new column in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261503/how-to-add-column-to-order-total-report-grid-and-display-custom-customer-data)

`app/code/Mymodule/Orderedproductsreport/view/adminhtml/layout/reports_report_product_sold_grid.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="adminhtml.report.grid.columnSet">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">report_product_sold</argument>
        <argument name="count_totals" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
    </arguments>
    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.report.grid.columnSet.sku" as="sku">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">SKU-*1</argument>
            <argument name="sortable" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">order_items_sku</argument>
            <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-sku</argument>
            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-sku</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="name">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product-1</argument>
            <argument name="sortable" xsi:type="string">5</argument>
            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">order_items_name</argument>
            <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">name</argument>
            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-product</argument>
            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-product</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="ordered_qty">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Ordered Quantity-1</argument>
            <argument name="sortable" xsi:type="string">10</argument>
            <argument name="total" xsi:type="string">sum</argument>
            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">number</argument>
            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">ordered_qty</argument>
            <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">ordered_qty</argument>
            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-qty</argument>
            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-qty</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Product, Ordered Quantity these two columns are calling from core file while SKU is calling from my custom module file.

SKU column is showing after Product, Ordered Quantity column.

**How can I move SKU before Product column?**

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hello [@Jimit Bhavsar](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/28140/jimit-bhavsar)

These are layout XML files, so we should be able to utilize [Layout Instructions](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_xml-instrux_before-after) on the block.

More specifically, you can use the `before="adminhtml.report.grid.columnSet.name"` attribute on your `SKU` column block:

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.report.grid.columnSet.sku" as="sku" before="adminhtml.report.grid.columnSet.name">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">SKU</argument>
        <argument name="sortable" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
        <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
        <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">order_items_sku</argument>
        <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
        <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-sku</argument>
        <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-sku</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Comment: it works, How do I add a filter for the column "SKU" in Reports Grid

Comment: Hi @Jaisa
I don't currently have a local environment to reference, but here is an article that shows how to add a filter: https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/how-to-add-a-custom-filter-to-the-product-grid-in-magento-2.html